# GCM CCS (XMPP) implementation in JAVA using smack library. Connection failed with gcm.googleapis.com

Tags: java, android, xmpp, google-cloud-messaging, smack

I am trying out GCM for communication between android client and a server application in java.
I am using XMPP based GCM as i need asynchronous, bidirectional messages.

On my client side, 
1. Google Play Service check showed that an update is required.

```
google play services is out of date. Requires 4242000 but found 3136130
```

Api level- 17, Using AVD with google API, Android 4.2.2
Google play services Revision 15
How can i solve this?

But i can successfully register the device.

On Server side, i use
2. I am using smack library 3.4.1
i used the sample code in google docs.
I get the following error

```
gcm.googleapis.com:5235 Exception: XMPPError connecting to gcm.googleapis.com:5235.; : remote-server-error(502)
  -- caused by: XMPPError connecting to gcm.googleapis.com:5235.: remote-server-error(502) XMPPError connecting to gcm.googleapis.com:5235.
  -- caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.connectUsingConfiguration(XMPPConnection.java:592)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.connect(XMPPConnection.java:1010)
    at SmackCcsClient.connect(SmackCcsClient.java:247)
    at SmackCcsClient.main(SmackCcsClient.java:341)
Nested Exception: 
XMPPError connecting to gcm.googleapis.com:5235.: remote-server-error(502) XMPPError connecting to gcm.googleapis.com:5235.
  -- caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.connectUsingConfiguration(XMPPConnection.java:565)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.connect(XMPPConnection.java:1010)
    at SmackCcsClient.connect(SmackCcsClient.java:247)
    at SmackCcsClient.main(SmackCcsClient.java:341)
Nested Exception: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(Unknown Source)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.connectUsingConfiguration(XMPPConnection.java:557)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.connect(XMPPConnection.java:1010)
    at SmackCcsClient.connect(SmackCcsClient.java:247)
    at SmackCcsClient.main(SmackCcsClient.java:341)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not connected to server.
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.sendPacket(XMPPConnection.java:483)
    at SmackCcsClient.send(SmackCcsClient.java:131)
    at SmackCcsClient.main(SmackCcsClient.java:356)
```

I have signed up the form for upstream messaging. but the approval is still pending. But the connection itself fails here. How can i solve this.

Please Help! 
Thank you in advance!!

Comment: how you imported your gcm_server_master demo project i am unable to import...Please help

Answer (score 1):

The `ERROR CODE 502` implies that there is problem with connecting SERVER, There might be several reasons but some common problem are,

1 ) `FIREWALL PROBLEM` ----[configure properly your firewall]

2 ) Server internal error ----[retry latter]

Comment: Thanks! How to check if it is the firewall problem. And if it is server internal error, how can i find that?? The server is gcm.googleapis.com