# Could not connect to Firebase for Cloud Messaging

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, xmpp, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to connect to the Firebase Cloud Messaging Server (CCS) using xmpp protocol in Node.js. So far I was unsuccessful.

I'm using node-xmpp-client library and it gives me the following error:

```js
{ [Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 64.233.191.188:5235]
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '64.233.191.188',
  port: 5235 }
```

and here is my code:

```js
var Client = require('node-xmpp-client');

var client = new Client({
  jid:      '<my sender id>@gcm.googleapis.com',
  password: '<my server key>',
  host:     'fcm-xmpp.googleapis.com',
  port:     5235
});

client.connection.socket.on('error', function (error) {
  console.log("socket error");
  console.error(error);
  process.exit(1);
});

client.on('online', function (data) {
  console.log('Connected as ' + data.jid.local + '@' + data.jid.domain + '/' + data.jid.resource);
});

client.on('error', function (err) {
  console.log("server error");
  console.error(err);
  process.exit(1);
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but maybe it's with your `jid` (gcm...) and `host` (fcm...). I think it should be same fcm? Can you try?

Comment: @intj thanks for the comment, but it failed too...

Comment: What about just using the sender id for your `jid`? Remove the `@gcm.googleapis.com`? I think I remember a similar post, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: @intj thank you for the followup. but it did't work either

Comment: Hey @JamshidAsadzadeh How was it? Are you still experiencing this error? Can you also verify what type of API key you're using?

Comment: I've also looked around for some possible similar posts and found these two: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22953528/4625829, http://stackoverflow.com/q/22325230/4625829
Both of the answers there are suggesting something about configuring the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Try with Client.Client and add legacySSl and preferredSaslMechanism

```
const XMPP = require('node-xmpp-client');
this._client = new XMPP.Client({
        jid: `${config.id}@gcm.googleapis.com`,
        password: config.key,
        port: config.port,
        host: config.host,
        legacySSL: true,
        preferredSaslMechanism: 'PLAIN'
      });
```

This works for me